# react native 0.43 post upgrade problems: clicking warning box(yellow box below) makes app crash down

Tags: react-native, version, upgrade

I tried to upgrade react-native from 0.42 to 0.43 and it seemsed alright without major error or conflicts. 
But when I run my app in simulator, clicking warning box at the bottom of screen(the yellow one), suddenly app crashes down.
ReactNative does not print any error log, so I tried it with xcode.
Error log is like below

```
2017-04-12 19:18:06.838 [error][tid:main][UIView+React.m:173] Invalid 
layout for (15)<RCTScrollView: 0x7ffa34e3cb70; reactTag: 15; frame = (0 
233; 414 0); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000223fc0>>. 
position: {207, nan}. bounds: {{0, 0}, {414, nan}}
2017-04-12 19:18:06.844 MyProject[17665:385202] *** Terminating app due 
to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer 
position contains NaN: [0 nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000112136d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000110b9921e objc_exception_throw + 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001121a02b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3 QuartzCore 0x00000001146aef92 _ .ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 152
4 QuartzCore 0x00000001146af107 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 44
5 QuartzCore 0x00000001146af772 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 650
6 UIKit 0x0000000114d079b4 -[UIWebDocumentView _notifyContentHostingLayersOfScaleChange] + 111
7 UIKit 0x0000000114d02b61 -[UIWebDocumentView setFrame:] + 287
8 UIKit 0x00000001150dfc95 -[UIWebBrowserView setFrame:] + 199
9 UIKit 0x0000000114d50fc9 -[UIWebView _frameOrBoundsChanged] + 508
10 UIKit 0x0000000114d51096 -[UIWebView setFrame:] + 166
11 MyProject 0x000000010ff121d9 -[RCTWebView layoutSubviews] + 185
12 UIKit 0x0000000114a8bab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
13 QuartzCore 0x00000001146b8bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
14 QuartzCore 0x00000001146ac440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
15 QuartzCore 0x00000001146ac2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
16 QuartzCore 0x000000011463a318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
17 QuartzCore 0x00000001146673ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
18 QuartzCore 0x0000000114667d6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
19 CoreFoundation 0x00000001120db267 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION + 23
20 CoreFoundation 0x00000001120db1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
21 CoreFoundation 0x00000001120bff8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
22 CoreFoundation 0x00000001120bf884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
23 GraphicsServices 0x0000000117c3ea6f GSEventRunModal + 161
24 UIKit 0x00000001149c6c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
25 MyProject 0x000000010fe3c5cf main + 111
26 libdyld.dylib 0x000000011639b68d start + 1
27 ??? 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

is there any idea?

UPDATE:
Simply deleting ios/build folder has solved the crash!
but I have a new question.. when I clicked an yellow warning box, views in my screen disappears and are shown again with closing the warning box. I believe a warning box was semi-transparent and I could see the views in my screen through the yellow box until react native 0.42.

So I tried a whole new project with react-native init.

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}} onLayout={e =>console.log(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
        Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
        Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
      </Text>
  <ScrollView style={styles.container} onLayout={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1}}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome to React Native!
      </Text>
      {data.map(d => <Text>{d}</Text>)}
      <Text style={styles.instructions}>
        To get started, edit index.ios.js
      </Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

above code produces a warning message about 'key prop' in views returned from data.map function.
When I click the yellow box to maximize it, the two onLayout functions print '0' and then actual values again when I close the box.
Is it intended from react native?

Comment: Please share any relevant code as well.

Comment: @dmorrow I am sorry but this is just an error occurred when I clicked warning box.. what kind of code you mean?

Comment: @dmorrow I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It was a bug and fixed at react native 0.44
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.44.0